# Cache in Azure App Service Easy Auth and B2C

Tags: azure-web-app-service, azure-ad-b2c, identity-experience-framework

I'm trying to configure Azure App Service Easy Auth with Azure AD B2c and it seems to be a cache.

I've created a new policy using they Identity Experience Framework and updated the settings but chrome network tools still registers a redirect to the old policy in the `?p=b2c_1_signuporsignin` instead of my custom `?p=b2c_1a_signup_or_signin_custom`

Copying the exact same config to another slot in the same app service works perfect.

Thus it seems like there is some kind of internal caching in the App Service. Testing the login using "Run now" works perfect but just browsing to `/.auth/login/aad` throws `Bad Request`

Is this a known issue?

(I have cleared all browser caches, used incognito, tried with Safari and still the same issue. And I also see the 302 from Azure so it is not a browser issue)

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm that the exact same config works now without any change in config. So it seems indeed like it is a cache or delay issue.